# Построение кроссворда

Tags: алгоритм

Вот для себя пробую понять следующую задачу, заинтересовала.
Условия указанные по ссылке ниже
http://uchebilka.ru/other/10719/index.html
Мне не ясно по какому принципу строиться тот кроссворд
и как они определяют это, где n – количество других слов, пересекающих рассматриваемое.
Пример какой то не правильный.

Answer (score 2):

задача np-сложная. надо составить все возможные кроссворды, вычислить для них стоимость, выбрать максимальную.
Берем первое слово, пересекаем его со вторым всеми возможными способами (если нельзя пересечь, берем вместо второго слова третье, второе ставим в конец списка слов). Для каждого способа пересечения берем третье слово, пересекаем с первыми двумя всеми возможными способами без учета буквы пересечения первых двух слов... и так далее.

В примере такой кроссворд, там съехала разметка просто:

```
  р
 мор
роман
 са
 тн
  т
  и
  к
  а
```

Comment: что значит пересекаем?

Comment: например слово "роман" пересекается со словом "мор" 3-я способами:

1)

    м
    о
    роман

2)
 
     м
    роман
     р

3)

    роман
      о
      р